# Git Bash vs. cmd colors in command pipenv

Tags: cmd, git-bash, pipenv

Is it possible to set Git Bash to show text with the same colors as cmd in command `pipenv install`?
Comparison here:
[image: here]

Answer (score 0):

go to C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile.d\git-prompt.sh and change it there you might mess up something but it will be changed there!